# Need Help Solving a Memory Leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am writing an inventory management system using dynamic arrays using objects. The strategy for this is NOT to use vectors, but allocate a dynamic array that 1 increment by 1 every time the client needs to add to the inventory. I am getting a "segmentation fault" error so I believe it is a memory leak.

I have tried rewriting it to match addresses but no luck. I think the buildItem function produces a temporary object, which is destroyed when the function ends. I don't know how to fix this though.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class InventoryObject {
private:
  int itemNumber;
  string description;
  int qty;
  float price;

public:
  int getItemNum() { return itemNumber; }
  string getDescription() { return description; }
  int getQty() { return qty; }
  float getPrice() { return price; }

  void storeInfo(int p, string d, int q, float pr);
  void showValues(InventoryObject &item);
};

// Function Implementation
void InventoryObject::storeInfo(int p, string d, int q, float pr) {
  itemNumber = p;
  description = d;
  qty = q;
  price = pr;
}

void InventoryObject::showValues(InventoryObject &item) {
  cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << endl;
  cout << "Part Number  : " << item.getItemNum() << endl;
  cout << "Description  : " << item.getDescription() << endl;
  cout << "Quantity:    : " << item.getQty() << endl;
  cout << "Price        : " << item.getPrice() << endl << endl;
}

// Function Prototypes for Client Program
InventoryObject buildItem();
void drawMenu();
void showValues(InventoryObject &);
void printInventory(int size);

int main() {
  int size = 1;
  int choice;
  bool quit = false;
  InventoryObject part;
  InventoryObject *iArray = new InventoryObject[size];
  drawMenu();
  cin >> choice;
  while (quit == false) {
    if (choice == 1) {
      InventoryObject item;
      item = buildItem();
      iArray[size] = item;
    }
    if (choice == 2) {
      iArray[size].showValues(iArray[size]);
    }
    if (choice == 3) {
      quit = true;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

// This function accepts the data from the client and creates a new
// InventoryObject object. The object is then supposed to be added to the
// dynamic array.
InventoryObject buildItem() {
  InventoryObject *tempObject = new InventoryObject;
  int itemNum;
  string description;
  int qty;
  float price;

  cout << "Enter data for the item you want to enter:\n\n";
  cout << "Item Number: \n";
  cin >> itemNum;
  cout << "Description: \n";
  cin.get();
  getline(cin, description);
  cout << "Quantity: \n";
  cin >> qty;
  cout << "Unit price: \n";
  cin >> price;

  tempObject->storeInfo(itemNum, description, qty, price);
  return *tempObject;
}

void drawMenu() {
  cout << "1. Add Inventory\n";
  cout << "2. Display Inventory\n";
  cout << "3. Quit Program\n";
}
```

I expect the object to be created, and put into the dynamic array. Then redraw the menu and interact with the client from there.

Comment: Why are you deleting `iArray` immediately after allocating ?

Comment: Why are you using manual memory management in the first place? What's wrong with `std::vector`?

Comment: There is obviously several misunderstanding shown by this code. But it's not clear to me exactly what the reasoning was for most of them. It's hard to know exactly what information you are missing. Maybe if you could describe what you expect each part of your code to do, it would help us understand which part you misunderstand. Right now, there are just too many mistakes to know where to start explaining.

Comment: A segmentation fault indicates a pointer error. It does not indicate a memory leak. Memory leaks cause a program's memory requirement to grow over time. It may lead to a `std::bad_alloc` but it shouldn't cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I updated the post and included the entire source code. Here is my goal: I want to use a class to make instances of inventory items that the client is adding to their inventory management system. I am having a lot of troubl just setting up the data structure, which is a dynamic array.

Comment: I'm just kind of lost at this point. This is an assignment for an introductory C++ class so there is probably a lot of stupid errors.

Comment: @DanielRamos More code it not very helpful. What is needed is a breakdown of your expectations of what each part of the code *does* and why.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::vector`? If you are, just skip the whole dynamic array stuff, use a `std::vector` and save yourself a lot of time.

Comment: @churill That's what I heard was best, but my professor does not want us to use vectors for this assignment unfortunately

Comment: Suggestion: Write code in small amounts. Write a few lines. Compile. Test. This makes it easier to find where a bug is. It's almost always in or exposed by the last few lines you added. Organize the code into small and simple functions that do only one thing (and do it well) and you can easily test each function separately before assembling the functions into a program with complex behaviour. Think of it like playing with Lego: You don't have a Saturn 5 rocket, You have a bucket of building blocks you turn into a Saturn 5 rocket.

Comment: The segmentation fault is due to the lines `iArray[size] = item;` and `iArray[size].showValues(iArray[size]);` where `[size]` should be `[size - 1]` because array indexes in C++ start from 0 and you have allocated `size` number of bytes.

Comment: @Ruks That fixed that issue! Thanks alot

Comment: @DanielRamos The code still does not work as you expect. Your `iArray` only ever handles 1 `InventoryObject`, the last one in the array.

Comment: The other approach is to use `malloc` if you really want to go old-school, because then you can use `realloc` to grow and automatically copy your data. It doesn't help if you have pointers into your data, but the same is true of vector when it resizes.

Comment: Arrays are 0 based, so `iArray[size] = item;` could potentially overrun your buffer if you're not careful.

Comment: The idea that the array only grows one element at at time is horrible. `std::vector` doubles its capacity for a very good reason.

Answer (score 2):

The **main** problem is that you are writing past the area of memory you allocated for your array (`iArray`).

Specifically, this line of code:

```
iArray[size] = item;
```

Should actually be:

```
iArray[size - 1] = item;
```

---

The above does not cause memory leak, but something else you do in your program does:

Your function `buildItem` does this when it returns the value of a pointer without first deleting the pointer.

To fix this, change

```
InventoryObject *tempObject = new InventoryObject;
```

to

```
InventoryObject tempObject;
```

And finally, remember to delete `iArray` before `return 0;` in main

```
delete[] iArray
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Build your program with debug symbol (-g flag)
2. Run limit-c unlimited
3. Run your program until it crashes
4. Run gdb  core where  is the name of your program
5. In the gdb climate type bt.

You should now have a back trace of where your program is crashing

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, here my observations:

1. The function `buildItem` must return a pointer of `InventoryObject` i mean: `InventoryObject*`. It is bease you are returning the pointer of the memory that was reserved at the moment of create it (`InventoryObject *tempObject = new InventoryObject;`), like this:

```cpp
InventoryObject* buildItem() {
  InventoryObject *tempObject = new InventoryObject;

  //...

  tempObject->storeInfo(itemNum, description, qty, price);
  return *tempObject;
}
```

> keep in mind that your main array (`InventoryObject *iArray`) contains an array of pointer.

2. The main problem that i see. In the `main` you are using an `if` block where there is a **local variable** called *item* (`InventoryObject item`). Let me explain something: Each instance of a class, like you `InventoryObject item` will be destroyed, release its memory, if its context is over.

So, in this case, the problem is that you was casting the pointer of at the moment of returning from the function `buildItem` (`return *tempObject`) and store its value into a local variable `InventoryObject item` which shall be release when the thread leaves the `if`, the context of the local variable.

Change your local variable `InventoryObject item` to handle a pointer: `InventoryObject* item`

```cpp
    if (choice == 1) {
      InventoryObject* item;
      item = buildItem();
      iArray[size] = item;
    }
```

> I recommend you to read the chapters **7. Pointers, Arrays, and References** and **17 Construction, Cleanup, Copy, and Move** from the book  **The C++ Programming Language** of *Bjarne Stroustrup*.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried rewriting it to match addresses but no luck. I think the buildItem function produces a temporary object, which is destroyed when the function ends.

Your intuition is half true. There is something wrong with this function, but it has nothing to do with temporaries. It's more about you allocating an object you never destroy.

The problem is that you are trying to do something similar to [what I was trying to do in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56639607/10957435), but not quite. Even if you were doing what I was doing, it still wouldn't be a good idea for reasons that lots of people already explained better than I could.

The point is is that the base of the issue is that is if you use `new` to allocate something, you **must** use `delete` to deallocate it, which you don't do here.

```
InventoryObject buildItem() {
  InventoryObject *tempObject = new InventoryObject;
  //...
  return *tempObject;
}
```

You simply return the object by value without deleting it first. You aren't even returning it by reference which would be better (yet still probably bad: again, see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56639607/10957435)). You are allocating an object and never deleting it. That's a leak.

You have two solutions: either return the pointer directly (if you really need a pointer) like this:

```
InventoryObject* buildItem() {
  InventoryObject *tempObject = new InventoryObject;
  //...
  return tempObject;
}
```

Or, you can simply just return the object by value like this:

```
InventoryObject buildItem() {
  InventoryObject tempObject;
  //...
  return tempObject;
}
```

Given the code sample you've shown, this is my recommendation of the two.

---

Note: I should mention that if for some reason you do need to return a pointer and have some factory method pattern with some sort of polymorphism in play, you also have the option of [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) too. That is what I ended up doing based on other people's suggestions from the other thread. I can personally recommend it. Basically, your code code would become something like this instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<InventoryObject> buildItem() {
  std::unique_ptr<InventoryObject> tempObject = new InventoryObject; // C++11 way, I think
                  // C++14 and above has a function called make_unique you could use instead.
  //...
  return tempObject;
}
```

However, this is only useful if you have some sort of polymorphism going on as I did. Given the code sample you have posted so far, you really only need to return by value in your situation. I just thought I'd mention this other option too, just in case.

---

P. (P.) S. This answer is only about your suspected memory leak. That said, there are other helpful answers here that you should heed. Problems described in other answers could contribute to your problem and could really trip you up down the road (actually, could still trip you up now too) if you don't fix them, so I highly recommend taking their advice too.