# Why sizeof(this - id) returns 8?

Tags: c++

I had a very stupid typo in my code...

```
is.read((char*)&this->id, sizeof(this-id));
```

missing `>` character after `this-`

Interestingly `sizeof(this - id)` returned 8!

What I think is... since `this` is a pointer, doing subtraction on `this` will result in another pointer that is off by value of id which can be anything depending on the value of id.

And... on 64 bit system, pointer is usually 8 bytes!

Am I correct? or missing something?

Below is the class I have.

```
class IndexItem : public Serializable {
public:
  IndexItem(uint32_t id, std::streampos pos) :
    id(id),
    pos(pos)
  { }
  uint32_t id;
  std::streampos pos;
protected:
  std::ostream& Serialize(std::ostream& os) const override {
    os.write((char*)&this->id, sizeof(this->id));
    os.write((char*)&this->pos, sizeof(this->pos));
    return os;
  }

  std::istream& Deserialize(std::istream& is) override {
    is.read((char*)&this->id, sizeof(this->id));
    is.read((char*)&this->pos, sizeof(this->pos));
    return is;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct. You can add or subtract integral types to any pointer, resulting in another pointer and `sizeof(this-id)=sizeof(this)` which happens to be 8 in your system.

Comment: Technically this pointer subtraction is undefined behavior but we have the saving grace that the operand of sizeof is [unevaluated and therefore this avoids undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28714018/1708801).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, is it undefined even if you do not dereference the result of the subtraction? In any case, as you say since this happens inside sizeof there is no UB here.

Comment: Note: Boost subtracts pointers for the SharedMemory API in order to get an offset (this - blah) or offset_ptr so they can store containers in the memory block and retrieve it with another program reading the same memory block (via offset + this).