# What does this syntax " decltype(*(T*)(0)**(U*)(0)) " mean?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading [this question on isocpp FAQ here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language-misc#suffix-return), this question is explaining how to write the return type for `???`

```
template<class T, class U>
??? mul(T x, U y)
{
return x*y;
}
```

I understand the easy way is to write `auto mul(T x, U y) -> decltype(x*y)`, however the question also gives another way, which is to replace `???` by `decltype(*(T*)(0)**(U*)(0))`. But I don't fully understand what this `decltype(*(T*)(0)**(U*)(0))` is really doing, it seems that it is declaring a temporary pointer `T*` and initialize it to zero and then dereference the pointer, then multiplied by the same counterpart for type `U`, is my understanding right?

But why using pointers? I think `decltype(T(0)*U(0))` or `decltype(T{0}*U{0})` should also work.

Comment: That assumes that `T` and `U` have a constructor that takes a single integer parameter. The pointer way makes no assumptions about the constructors of `T` and `U`.

Comment: Note, it is not undefined behavior since it is [in an unevaluated context](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28723577/1708801)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
decltype(*(T*)(0)**(U*)(0))
```

Let's split it up:

```
(T*)(0) //cast a null pointer to a T*
*(T*)(0) //dereference, giving a T

(U*)(0) //cast a null pointer to a U*
*(U*)(0) //dereference, giving a U

(*(T*)(0)) * (*(U*)(0)) //the result of multiplying a U and a T
```

`decltype(T(0)*U(0))` is equivalent only if `T` and `U` have constructors taking a single `int` (or something which can be implicitly converted to from an integer literal).

The standard library already has a [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) to do this in a cleaner fashion:

```
decltype(std::declval<T>() * std::declval<U>())
```

Answer (score 0):

this indeed error prone.

in your solution , you basically assume the construcor can get `0` as argument, and that may not be the case.

the snippet basically cast `NULL` to some `T` object pointer, then pull out `T` with the `*` operator, now we left with   basically `decltype({T object}*{U object})` it assumes that in compile time, the `decltype` will be replaced by the real type and in run time there will be no pointers. but this code is very ugly and un-maintainable.

a better solution is to use C++11 `std::result_of` :
`typename std::result_of<declval<T>()*declval<U>()>::type`

`declval` does something similar to `*(T*)(0)` only it returns *r-value reference* (meaning `T&&`)

Comment: That's not what `result_of` is for, and it wouldn't compile here.